# Using external abstract class in Typescript without extending it

Tags: typescript, oop, typescript-typings

I've got one module called `utils.tsx` so that:

```
interface IUtils {
    toUri: (route: string) => string
}

export default abstract class Utils implements IUtils {
    public toUri = (route: string) => {
        return route
    }
}
```

and another file where I wish to use this utils module:

```
 import Utils from '../helpers/utils'

 class Router  {
     private getBuilder = (search: string) => {
       const path = Utils.toUri(search)
     }
 }
```

When I am trying to use `Utils.toUri` I am getting TS error:

`[ts] Property 'toUri' does not exist on type 'typeof Utils'.`

My intention is to call the external abstract class function without extending the `Router` class nor inheriting from it (as I will have more than one external module in the main file).

Could someone help me to bypass it and understand?

PS: I tried with `public abstract toUri()` too. Perhaps I mixed up the routines from other programming languages and confusing usage of *static* with *abstract* here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `Utils` to implement `IUtils`, since `Utils` is the *instance* type of the class.  It looks like you want the `Utils` *constructor* (whose type is `typeof Utils`) to implement `IUtils`.  That is, you want `toUri` to be a *static* method of the `Utils` class.  Like this:

```
abstract class Utils  {
  public static toUri = (route: string) => {
    return route
  }
}
```

There is no way to annotate the `class Utils` declaration to say that the static side of the class implements `IUtils`.  Luckily, the `Utils` constructor will automatically be seen as something that implements `IUtils` without needing to write `implements IUtils` anywhere.  Thanks, [structural typing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing):

```
declare function takeIUtils(iUtils: IUtils): void;
takeIUtils(Utils); // works anyway
```

This should allow your `Router` class to behave as desired.

---

Side note, I wonder if you really want `Utils` to be a *class* at all.  If you never want to see an instance of `Utils` like `class X extends Utils {...}; new X()`, then you're probably making life unnecessarily hard for yourself.  Maybe it should just be a *value*:

```
export const Utils : IUtils = {
  toUri(route: string) {
    return route
  }
}
```

Or a [`namespace`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html):

```
export namespace Utils {
  export function toUri(route: string) {
    return route
  }
}
```

Or a module, or something.

---

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes, definitely `namespace` is a solution to my problems. Thank you. :)